# How do I create new columns to a dataframe using lambdas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I would like to create 3 new columns in this dataframe:

```
columnList = { 'hasCampaign': ( lambda x: x[ 'CAMPAIGNID' ] != '' ), 
               'hasLeadType': ( lambda x: x[ 'LEADTYPE' ] != '' ),
               'hasEvent': ( lambda x: x[ 'EVENT' ] != '' ) }
for ( k, v ) in columnList.items():
    df = df.assign( k = v )
```

Shouldn't that work? I get this error:

```
KeyError: 'CAMPAIGNID'
```

I've verified and the column CAMPAIGNID exists.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2524             try:
-> 2525                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2526             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
```

How do I assign these 3 lambdas to calculate these new 3 columns?

Comment: What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: Can you share a small portion of the dataframe you're trying to apply this to? And an example of what you want the output dataframe to look like? That will help a lot to give a bit more context

Comment: Thank you!

@the_martian I was trying to create new True/False columns that indicate whether these columns had a value:  CAMPAIGNID, LEADTYPE, EVENT.

This is the dataframe:
`['ID', 'AMOUNT', 'CAMPAIGNID', 'LEADTYPE', 'EVENT', 'STARTDATE', 'DISCOUNTAMOUNT', 'DISCOUNTAPPROVED']`

Thank you, @jezrael !
This code did the trick:


`df = df.assign( **columnList )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working omit loop and use:

```
df = df.assign( **columnList )
```

for avoid `KeyError`s is possible convert columns to list, maybe some traling wtispaces problem:

```
print (df.columns.tolist())
```

and for remove whitespaces in columns names use:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

Comment: Thank you! That resolved it!

`df = df.assign( **columnList )`